# List delegations on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there as way to list all existing delegations on an ActiveRecord class (or instance)?

I want to iterate through attributes on any call to `attributes=` and provide special logging for any delegated attributes.

*I'm on Rails 3, but a Rails 4 answer would also be of interest.*